# Parsing an email content with german characters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, sendgrid

I am receiving incoming mails through sendgrid. When I receive an email with German language that contains umlaut characters in the `params` it is showing the full content, but when I read and save, it is not saving after the umlaut character. I did a utf-8 conversion with

```
Iconv.conv('utf-8','ISO-8859-1' , str)
```

and, it is giving me the unicode string, but if I send the outgoing encoding as utf-8 in my gmail and send, it is working properly. I can't rely on it as my customers may send without utf8 setting. Please let me know what should be done.

Comment: Sure thanks .. i found the solution for the question i posted Iconv.new('utf-8', charset_encoding).iconv(text)

Answer (score 1):

I achieved Iconv.new('utf-8', charset_encoding).iconv(params[:text])